# Python Docx - How check if each table contain more than 5 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to programming in general,
***Situation***
Trying to create a script to open .docx file,
check for table,
if table has > 5 columns,
count the number of rows of those tables with > 5 columns.

***Stuck***
Stuck at how to check through each table automatically if it has > 5 columns,
and print out the number of rows in tables with > 5 columns

```
doctor = docx.Document()
doctor.tables
len(doctor.tables[0].columns)
len(doctor.tables[1].columns)
len(doctor.tables[2].columns)
len(doctor.tables[3].columns)
len(doctor.tables[4].columns)
len(doctor.tables[5].columns)
```

***Background***
Not all table in a word file holds the data I'm collecting, only table with > 5 columns will contain data I'm interested.
Using Docx library

[image: 1]

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, error, data, etc. Copy/post as formatted text.

Comment: Iterate over `doctor.tables` and check `len(table.columns)`

Comment: @buran Do you mean for loop? Do you mind writing out abit so I have a better idea, Thank you so much

Comment: @buran Thank you for the heads up. I'm able to count the column in each table, next step will be writing an if statement to filter out?

Answer (score 0):

```
doctor = docx.Document()
for table in doctor.tables:
    print(len(table.columns))
    if len(table.columns) > 5:
        # do something
```

Note that dealing with tables can be a challenge due to merged cells, etc.

Comment: next step will be writing an if statement to filter out?

Comment: yes, that would be the next steps if you want to process only tables based on condition.